# how to find the irfunction's enclosing class in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

In kotlin, i have an Irfunction, how should i find which class it belongs to ?

```
abstract class IrFunction : IrDeclarationBase(), IrPossiblyExternalDeclaration,
        IrDeclarationWithVisibility, IrTypeParametersContainer, IrSymbolOwner, IrDeclarationParent,
        IrReturnTarget, IrMemberWithContainerSource, IrMetadataSourceOwner {
```

Sadly the documentation for Ir related concept is missing and I have to guess the meaning and my guess is not always correct.

Comment: From a web search, I'm guessing this is something to do with the Kotlin compiler itself…? It might help if you could add relevant tag(s) and/or explain what an ‘irfunction’ is.

Comment: Sadly there is no documentation for IrFunction from kotlin team.